# Definition of positive density

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a really quick question, which I could not find an answer to with some search on the internet... What is the definition of a subset $S$ of natural numbers having a positive density? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_n := \{ x \in S \mid x \le n \}$. [The (natural) density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) of $S$ is defined as
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\mid S_n \mid}n
$$
if the limit exists.

Therefore - without additional information - I'd say that $S$ has positive density if this limit exists and is greater than $0$.